# mysql - filter IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to refine this sql select:

```
SELECT ch_num, payment_type, Total FROM transactions WHERE ( ch_num ) 
IN (
SELECT ch_num FROM transactions GROUP BY ch_num HAVING count('ch_num') > 1 
)
ORDER BY `ch_num`
```

Result i get is:

```
ch_num  payment_type    Total 
20001   visa        36.60
20001   visa        36.60
20001   mc          30.60
50019   cash        9.00
50019   mc          18.95
50023   cash        2.70
50023   visa        7.00
```

But i need results rows only where there is 'cash' payment_type so 'ch_no' 20001 should be omited.
Correct result would be then:

```
ch_num  payment_type    Total 
50019   cash        9.00
50019   mc          18.95
50023   cash        2.70
50023   visa        7.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete, proven code example, with test results at the end. I used Oracle, but syntax should be the same for the SQL SELECT.

```
create table transactions (ch_num int, payment_type varchar2(100), total float);

insert into transactions values(20001,'visa',36.60);
insert into transactions values(20001,'mc',30.60);
insert into transactions values(50019,'cash',9.00);
insert into transactions values(50019,'mc',18.95);
insert into transactions values(50023,'cash',2.70);
insert into transactions values(50023,'visa',7.00);

SELECT ch_num, payment_type, Total FROM transactions a WHERE ( ch_num ) 
IN (
SELECT ch_num FROM transactions  GROUP BY ch_num HAVING count(ch_num) > 1 
)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT  ch_num FROM transactions b where payment_type = 'cash' and a.ch_num = b.ch_num)
ORDER BY ch_num
```

Results:

```
    CH_NUM  PAYMENT_TYPE    TOTAL
1   50019   cash    9
2   50019   mc  18.95
3   50023   cash    2.7
4   50023   visa    7
```

Comment: for some reason this select is little faster ( only measured in phpMyAdmin ).. any idea why?

Comment: @phpJs - You could look at the optimizer plan and compare them between the 2 queries, to see what is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ch_num, payment_type, Total
FROM transactions 
WHERE ch_num IN 
(
       SELECT ch_num 
       FROM transactions 
       GROUP BY ch_no
       HAVING count('ch_num') > 1 
       and sum(payment_type='cash') >= 1
)
ORDER BY `ch_num`
```